# React context value cannot pass to other components

Tags: reactjs

**context/cart.jsx**

```
import { useState, useContext, createContext, useEffect } from "react";

const CartContext = createContext()

const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [cart,setCart] = useState([])
    const cartTotal = cart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.quantity, 0)
   
    
    useEffect(() => {
        let existingCartItems = localStorage.getItem("cart")
        if(existingCartItems) setCart(JSON.parse(existingCartItems))
    }, [])

    console.log(cartTotal)

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={[cart, setCart, cartTotal]}>
            {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    )
}

const useCart = () => useContext(CartContext)

export { useCart, CartProvider }
```

**components/Header.jsx**

```
const Header = () => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useAuth()
    const [cart, cartTotal] = useCart()
    const categories = useCategory()

    console.log(cartTotal)
}
```

I am trying to pass the variable `cartTotal` to the header and to be displayed on the page. While the context could print out the value of `cartTotal` but when I try to print out on the header component it shows out the error that `function dispatchSetState(fiber, queue, action) { { if (typeof arguments[3] === 'function') { error("State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the " + 'second callback argument. To execute a side effect after ' + 'rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().'); } }` so can someone help find out some solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not logging `cartTotal`, you are logging `setCart`.

In the `value` of your `Provider` you pass an array, and unlike object, when destructuring an array the order of elements matters. `cardTotal` it the third elements in your array, so you should get it like this:

**components/Header.jsx**

```js
const [cart, setCart, cartTotal] = useCart();
```

You can also just change the array to an object:

**context/cart.jsx**

```js
<CartContext.Provider value={{ cart, setCart, cartTotal }}>
  {children}
</CartContext.Provider>
```

**components/Header.jsx**

```js
const { cart, cartTotal } = useCart();
```

Comment: Can you please specify the files because there are some confusion

Comment: @DSham Sure, done.

Comment: After changing to the above code it occurred ```Uncaught TypeError: useCart is not a function or its return value is not iterable```

Comment: @DSham check your implementation again and make sure your are not mixing up `[]` and `{}`

Comment: It works fine now